# Multiple string delimiters

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm a total beginner in the VB language and I have a string in the format:

> Smith, Alex (asmith@gmail.com)

I'm attempting to isolate "asmith" from this string. I'm assuming that we would have to split at the "(" and then at the "@" and obtain the 1st index?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are all of the inputs uniform? Do they strictly follow that pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm assuming that we would have to split at the "(" and then at the "@" and obtain the 1st index?

Your approach is correct. A literal translation of your algorithm to VB.NET would be:

```
Dim firstPartOfMailAddress = text.Split("("c)(1).Split("@"c)(0)
```

Explanation:

- `"("c` is a *character literal*. Split expects a character, not a string (that would be `"("`).
- Arrays are zero-based in VB.NET and indexed using the `(...)` operator. Thus, you take the second part `(1)` of the first split and the first part `(0)` of the second split.

Notes:

- This code does not include any error handling and will fail horribly if the text does not contain the character `(`.
- An alternative would be to extract the value using a regular expression, but if your are new to the language, splitting is a much easier option.

Comment: Exactly, what I'm looking for! In Python (what I program mostly in) it's very simple "Input String".split('(')[1].split('@')[0] .

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option for you:

```
Dim input = "Smith, Alex (asmith@gmail.com)"
Dim output= input.Split("("c, "@"c)(1)
```

Comment: Doesn't look like VB.NET?!?

Answer (score 1):

use class :

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class RegexUtilities
    Dim invalid As Boolean = False

    Public Function IsValidEmail(strIn As String) As Boolean
        invalid = False
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strIn) Then Return False

        ' Use IdnMapping class to convert Unicode domain names.
        Try
            strIn = Regex.Replace(strIn, "(@)(.+)$", AddressOf Me.DomainMapper,
                                  RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
        Catch e As RegexMatchTimeoutException
            Return False
        End Try

        If invalid Then Return False

        ' Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format.
        Try
            Return Regex.IsMatch(strIn,
                   "^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
                   "(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
                   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
        Catch e As RegexMatchTimeoutException
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Function DomainMapper(match As Match) As String
        ' IdnMapping class with default property values.
        Dim idn As New IdnMapping()

        Dim domainName As String = match.Groups(2).Value
        Try
            domainName = idn.GetAscii(domainName)
        Catch e As ArgumentException
            invalid = True
        End Try
        Return match.Groups(1).Value + domainName
    End Function
End Class
```

and use code in form and customzition :

```
Dim util As New RegexUtilities()
        Dim emailAddresses() As String = {"david.jones@proseware.com", "d.j@server1.proseware.com",
                                           "jones@ms1.proseware.com", "j.@server1.proseware.com",
                                           "j@proseware.com9", "js#internal@proseware.com",
                                           "j_9@[129.126.118.1]", "j..s@proseware.com",
                                           "js*@proseware.com", "js@proseware..com",
                                           "js@proseware.com9", "j.s@server1.proseware.com",
                                           """j\""s\""""@proseware.com", "js@contoso.中国"}

        For Each emailAddress As String In emailAddresses
            If util.IsValidEmail(emailAddress) Then
                Console.WriteLine("Valid: {0}", emailAddress)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid: {0}", emailAddress)
            End If
        Next
```